# Escape key for Safari using Selenium

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, java

I am using Selenium webdriver (Java) and ran into a problem.

I made the method,

```
    public void escape() {
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).build().perform();
    }
```

but it does not work for Safari. It works for all other browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome) except Safari. What will be the alternate escape method for Safari using selenium?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the error is in your code.

> action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).build().perform();

[perform](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#perform--) is meant to be called as a method of *sendKeys*, not as a method of [build](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#build--).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20266441/1106708) on SO has an example:

```
action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform();
```

Comment: Still does not work for Safari. It works for all other browsers except Safari.

Comment: thanks , this is working like a charm for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using robot class of java, following is the code.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code for escape key:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("myobject")).sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
```

to use this code, you need to add the below mentioned import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
```

Another way is using the robot keys, though i never prefer them, below is the code if it helps you:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java you can go with Robot Library.

```
 Robot r = new Robot();

 r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);

 r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```